# Three Way Many-to-Many in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have seen plenty of examples on the internet and answers on SO on various ways to establish many-to-many relation between two entities. The example of `Users` and `Roles` is often used. That problem is quite straight forward and simple to understand even for someone like me who only has about 2 months experience with MongoDb and half of that time has been spent fighting against the RDBMS schema patterns that aren't necessary in MongoDb.

However, I am a little lost trying to establish a three way many-to-many relation which seems straight forward in RDBMS world but I'm unable to think through as to how it would be done in MongoDb.

Here's the example.

Let's say I have three entities: `Project`, `User`, `ProjectRole`.

Each `User` can have multiple `Projects`, each `Project` can have multiple `Users`.

Each `User` can have multiple `ProjectRoles` and each `ProjectRole` can have multiple `Users`.

Another condition is that `ProjectRoles` can only be assigned to `Users` in relation to a `Project`. That is, `Users` can't have a `ProjectRole` if they're not part of a `Project`.

Similarly, `ProjectRoles` are only related to `Projects` via `Users`.

So there are some ways that I have thought about creating these relationships but obviously some of these (or maybe all) ways are a direct result of RDBMS way of doing things.

**1.**

**Create a `join` collection for these three entities** such that each document looks like this:

```
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("someuserid"),
    "project_id" : ObjectId("someprojectid"),
    "projectrole_id" : ObjectId("someprojectroleid")
}
```

**2.**

**Copy over `User` (embed) object to `Project` document with ProjectRole object/information also embedded**, it would look something like this:

```
{
    "name" : "ProjectName",
    "users" : [{ "username" : "FirstUserName", "projectRole" : "SomeRole" },
               { "username" : "SecondUserName", "projectRole": "SomeOtherRole"}]
}
```

**3.**

**Copy over (embed) `Project` object in the `User` document with the associated `ProjectRole` for that `User` in that `Project`**, that would be something like this:

```
{
    "name" : "UserName",
    "projects" : [{ "projectname" : "SomeProject", "projectRole" : "SomeRole"},
                  { "projectname" : "SomeOtherProject", "projectRole" : "SomeOtherRole"}]
}
```

Option 1 has the best chance of me being able to keep data clean and keep its integrity intact. But it is going to be a pain to read since it goes over 3 collections (and possibly more as the project gets more complex).

Option 2 and 3 seem, to me at least, like the most MongoDb style with embedded information. I prefer 2 over 3 because `Projects` are sort of higher in the hierarchy followed by `Users`. In other words, theoretically each `Project` will have a lot more `Users` than each `User` and the number of `Projects` they have been assigned.

Problem with Option 2 is data integrity. That can be dealt with by making sure that on each update, for example, of a `User` the server goes and searches through `Project` collection and updates all instances of this `User` object (matching on Id). This could potentially be an extremely slow operation (perhaps indexing on `UserId` would make it faster) but the priority is read-speed rather than quick updates. Also the assumption is that `User` data will remain fairly unchanged over a period of time (on the other hand `Project` data will get updated quite frequently).

Past this point I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. Am I at least on the right track or are all my solutions based on some fundamental misunderstanding of either MongoDb or even the actual problem itself?